# Error: Incompatible types in initialization? (iPhone,Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, types

I'm getting the error on "float pos = [sender value];"...sender should be a UISlider that I set up in Interface Builder.

**ButtonViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)slide: (id)sender {
 float pos = [sender value];
 loadValue.progress = pos;
}
```

**ButtonViewController.h**

```
@interface Button_Fun4ViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UIProgressView *loadValue;
}

- (IBAction)slide: (id)sender;
```

THANKS.

Comment: answer is good thank you but what's the point of declaring it as "id" then?

Comment: The reason it's an id here is that all target/action methods take an id and return nil (which IBAction is a macro for). addTarget:action:forEvents: is defined at the UIControl level, so has to work for all UIControls, not just UISliders. It comes from a longer history of target/action methods that all pass an id, so even casting to UIControl would be confusing for experienced developers. Technically you could type the parameter to UISlider, and it would probably work, but it would probably create more surprise than it solved (since the call still wouldn't actually be type-safe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While sender "should" be a UISlider, the compiler doesn't know that. All it sees is `id`, which it binds to the first matching method signature it can find; probably one that returns something other than a float (and as a final guess, the compiler will assume it returns an `id`).

You'll need to typecast this over to UISlider in this case:

```
- (IBAction)slide: (id)sender {
    float pos = [(UISlider *)sender value];
    loadValue.progress = pos;
}
```

Using `NSAssert()` or an `if()` to double-check that this is fact a `UISlider` wouldn't be a bad idea, but isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: The cast to UISlider * should be before sender, but within the brackets. Now you cast the return value of [sender value] to a UISlider *

Answer (score 1):

Since sender is of type 'id', the compiler doesn't know what it will return from its messages, and assumes they'll return an 'id' typed value. You need to either cast sender to UISlider (so the compiler knows that -value returns a float), or cast the returned value of the message to a float.

Comment: When I try to do this: "float pos = (float) [sender value];" it gives me error: "Pointer value used where floating point value was expected". What does this mean?

Comment: You can't do it this way. The compiler assumes that [sender value] is an id, and you can't cast an id (an object pointer) to a float. You have to cast the sender to the right type so that the compiler knows what the return type of -value is.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sender` is of type `id` you should indicate what type it is.

Use the following:

```
float pos = [(UISlider *)sender value];
```

Alternatively, you can use protocols. That way, you can receive different types of objects which, as long as they adhere to the protocol, can all be used in the same way.

```
@protocol myProtocol {
-(float)value;
}

-(void)myMethod:(id<myProtocol>)sender {
    float pos = [sender value];
}
```

Comment: with the latter syntax (cast to float) you can send any type of object, as long as it responds to the `value` message, and the result of the `value` method can be cast to a float. The type of object doesn't matter there. Alternatively, if you don't like casting, you can use protocols. `id<protocol> sender` in the declaration.

Comment: You can't cast it to float at this point because the compiler still thinks that -value is returning an id at this point, and so won't be willing to cast to float. This would work for any object value return, but not for a float. Float return values are done differently in ObjC than object return values (it can't use objc_msgSend(), it has to use objc_msgSend_fpret()).

Comment: True.. I'll change the answer to reflect the comment.